# JQuery mobile changing element between list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two lists and when clicked on one element I want to remove it from this list and add it to a second one.

```
<div id="ul1">
    <ul id="selected">
       <li><a href ="" data-para1="111">Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href ="" data-para1="121">Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href ="" data-para1="131">Item 3</a></li>
       <li><a href ="" data-para1="141">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="ul2">
    <ul id="list2">
       <li><a href ="" data-para1="11">Item 10</a></li>
       <li><a href ="" data-para1="21">Item 20</a></li>
       <li><a href ="" data-para1="31">Item 30</a></li>
       <li><a href ="" data-para1="41">Item 40</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am not a jQuery dev and I can't have this working properly.

```js
$("#ul1 a").click(function(){
   var para1 = this.dataset['para1'];
   $(this).closest('li').remove();
   add2(para1);

   return false;
});

 
$("#ul2 a").click(function(){
   var para1 = this.dataset['para1'];
   $(this).closest('li').remove();
   add(para1);

   return false;
});

function add(p1){
    $("#selected").append('<li><a href="" data-para1='+p1+'>'+p1+'</a></li>');

    return false;
}

function add2(p1){
  $("#list2").append('<li><a href="" data-para1='+p1+'>'+p1+'</a></li>');

  return false;
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could point out the correct solution to accomplish this.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JrJck/235/).
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use appendTo method.

```
$("#ul1").on('click', 'a', function(){
       $(this).closest('li').appendTo('#list2');
    return false;
});
$("#ul2").on('click', 'a', function(){
      $(this).closest('li').appendTo('#selected');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working better. However, when I click on an item from the second list, it goes to the 1st list but when clicking again to this item on the first list it doesn't go back to 2nd list as expected.

Any idea about this? It seems that the function called is still:

$("#ul2").on('click', 'a', function()

Even if the link is now in the ul1 div.

http://jsfiddle.net/JrJck/238/

Comment: you have to bind click event to the #ul element not link. The proper way to do this is: `$("#ul1").on('click', 'a', function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this snippet. It checks the `click()` event of the anchor inside the li, looks for the li by matching the father of the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select li a').each(function(index, anchor) {
    // Let's add a click listener
    $(anchor).click(function(){
      // Let's find the father li
      $(this).closest('li').appendTo('#append');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ul1">
    <ul id="select">
       <li><a href ="#" data-para1="111">Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href ="#" data-para1="121">Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href ="#" data-para1="131">Item 3</a></li>
       <li><a href ="#" data-para1="141">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="ul2">
    <ul id="append">
       <li><a href ="#" data-para1="11">Item 10</a></li>
       <li><a href ="#" data-para1="21">Item 20</a></li>
       <li><a href ="#" data-para1="31">Item 30</a></li>
       <li><a href ="#" data-para1="41">Item 40</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
      function move(ul1,ul2) {

         $('body').on('click',ul1+" a", function(){

                   $(ul2).append($(this).parent('li'));
                   //$(this).parent('li').remove();
                return false;
            });
};
        move('#selected','#list2');
        move('#list2','#selected');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x9LL1ubc/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
$("#ul1 a").click(function(){
    var para1 = $(this).closest('li').html()
   $(this).closest('li').remove();
   add2(para1);
return false;
});


$("#ul2 a").click(function(){
    var para1 = $(this).closest('li').html()
   $(this).closest('li').remove();
   add(para1);
return false;
});

function add(p1){
    ("#list2").append(p1);
return false;
}

function add2(p1){
  $("#list2").append(p1);
    return false;
}
```